# Priority of dhcp servers

Tags: networking, ip, dhcp, ipv4

Let say there is a main Server which is assigning ips by dhcp to  50 different LAN ports in network.Now if at some LAN port we connect a small router on the  yellow port(so that all other devices come in network)dhcp enabled,then it will also act as a server with some new ips,Now if any new device connects it will have a two options to request IP one from main server and other from router.But only main server can provide internet,so my question is how can I priorities new network to request IP from main server not from router...?

Answer (score 2):

With IPv6 you can give DHCP servers priorities, but with IPv4 you'll just get unpredictable results. So for IPv4: don't connect multiple DHCP servers to one network unless you know what you're doing and you are building a redundant setup with DHCP servers that know how to synchronise with each other.

That is clearly not the case here.